# Add button to forward message from channel in Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm not quite sure it's possible but probably someone did that. Is it possible to use bot for appending button to message user forwarded to bot? I mean:

1. Admin posted a message in his channel.
2. Admin forwarded message to bot (assume bot added in channel).
3. Bot appends to original message in channel with button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is yes - it can be done with [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) API method:

```
curl 
  --request POST \
  --url https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_SECRET_TOKEN}/editMessageReplyMarkup \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "chat_id": {CHANNEL_ID},
    "message_id": {CHANNEL_MESSAGE_ID},
    "reply_markup": {
        "inline_keyboard": [
            [
                {
                    "text": "Hello world!",
                    "url": "https://google.com"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}'
```